# CSS a:hover and a:active not working

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to learn `HTML` and `CSS` and was testing out some simple `CSS` when strange things started happening.

Here is my `CSS`.

```
a:link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: purple;
    text-decoration: dotted;
}
a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: dotted;
}
a:active {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: dotted;
}
```

`a:hover` and `a:active` do not always do what they're supposed to. It's really confusing me because if I change the `blue` in `a:hover's` `color: blue;` to `black` it suddenly works.

I am editing the `HTML` and `CSS` files in Visual Studio 2012 and opening them in Google Chrome from the Dropbox folder they're saved in.

Comment: `a:hover and a:active do not always do what they're supposed to` how so?

Comment: Have you considered changing colors to another other than blue and black for a.hover{}?

Comment: @jmore009 The do not to what I tell them to. E.g. `color: blue;` does not make the color blue. It does nothing.  
  
@Kenyanke Yes, blue is the only color I've tried that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

How can you differentiate between `a:link` and `a:hover`? Normally, it's `a:link` that's blue. Now, when you hover over it, it's `a:hover` that's also blue. Changing `a:hover` to black will let you see the difference.

Comment: Sorry; the links are all visited so they are all displaying as purple right now.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

1. In order for `a:link` to work you have to include a an actual link (`href="somewebsite"`). Otherwise you should be  targeting just the `a`.
2. A lot of people think the `active` state is after you clicked on it thus making it "active" but it's on mousedown. Click the link and hold the mouse to see the `:active` triggered
3. In your example you have `a:link` AND `a:hover` set to blue so you will see no change when you hover over it.
4. `text-decoration: dotted` is not a property. You can choose from `none`, `underline`, `overline`, `line-through`, `initial` and `inherit`

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pe2p5ozn/2/)

```
a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: 1. I have `href = "somefile"`. Does that count?  
3. Sorry; I should clarify. The links are all visited so they are purple at the moment.
4. dotted was a suggestion from Visual Studio. I will try changing it to one of the ones you listed.

Comment: @Chiharu yeah just including `href` should work, like I said, you could always just use `a` instead of `a:link`. Is anything else not working as expected?

Comment: I changed `dotted` to `underline` and `a:hover`'s color and text-decoration worked, but when I tried removing the text-decoration the color stopped working again.

Comment: do you have a link you can post? or can you recreate this in a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rjenz0ok/

I'm not sure if we can recreate the problem since the links don't work and can't be changed to visited though.

Comment: @Chiharu well the `hover` color and the link `color` are still both "blue", so when you remove the `text-decoration` theres just no way to differentiate between the two, change the color of one of them like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/rjenz0ok/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/rjenz0ok/1/)

Comment: But the thing is when they were visited/purple every color worked for hover except blue which is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @Chiharu they seem to work fine here, click one of those links so it's "visited" (I changed your paths to google and yahoo): [http://jsfiddle.net/rjenz0ok/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/rjenz0ok/3/)